# Replace multiple values in Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given the following example array:

```py
import numpy as np

example = np.array(
  [[[   0,    0,    0,  255],
    [   0,    0,    0,  255]],

   [[   0,    0,    0,  255],
    [ 221,  222,   13,  255]],

   [[-166, -205, -204,  255],
    [-257, -257, -257,  255]]]
)
```

I want to replace values `[0, 0, 0, 255]` values with `[255, 0, 0, 255]` and everything else becomes `[0, 0, 0, 0]`.

So the desired output is:

```py
[[[   255,    0,    0,  255],
  [   255,    0,    0,  255]],

 [[   255,    0,    0,  255],
  [     0,    0,    0,    0]],

 [[     0,    0,    0,    0],
  [     0,    0,    0,    0]]
```

This solution got close:

```py
np.place(example, example==[0, 0, 0,  255], [255, 0, 0, 255])
np.place(example, example!=[255, 0, 0, 255], [0, 0, 0, 0])
```

But it outputs this instead:

```py
[[[255   0   0 255],
  [255   0   0 255]],

 [[255   0   0 255],
  [  0   0   0 255]], # <- extra 255 here

 [[  0   0   0   0],
  [  0   0   0   0]]]
```

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all occurrences of `[0, 0, 0, 255]` using

```
np.all(example == [0, 0, 0, 255], axis=-1)
# array([[ True,  True],
#        [ True, False],
#        [False, False]])
```

Save these positions to a `mask`, set everything to zero, then place the desired output into the `mask` positions:

```
mask = np.all(example == [0, 0, 0, 255], axis=-1)
example[:] = 0
example[mask, :] = [255, 0, 0, 255]
# array([[[255,   0,   0, 255],
#         [255,   0,   0, 255]],
# 
#        [[255,   0,   0, 255],
#         [  0,   0,   0,   0]],
# 
#        [[  0,   0,   0,   0],
#         [  0,   0,   0,   0]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 255])
replace = np.array([255, 0, 0, 255])

m = (example - a).any(-1)
np.logical_not(m)[...,None] * replace

array([[[255,   0,   0, 255],
        [255,   0,   0, 255]],

       [[255,   0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]]])
```